# Get the index of values in a Pandas Dataframe column that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

*Hey guys, first time posting here so im going to try to give as much detail as possible without boring yall. Thanks for reading in advance!*

So I have a data set of about 50K rows and 5 cols in Dataframe format. I read in the values from a csv file by the following command

```
df=pd.read_csv(path,usecols=inputs)
```

Inputs is a list of strings which correspond to a column in the csv file. I am analyzing a bunch of movies so the inputs looks like

```
inputs=['revenue','budget','rating','popularity','runtime']
```

I want to "clean up" this Dataframe by removing all the zero values and the outliers. I remove all the zero values with the snippet below (inputs is a list of all the col names from the csv I am reading in.

```
df = df[(df[inputs] != 0).all(axis=1)]
```

It looks like the program is correctly removing all the zeros. **It removes all zeros from the Dataframe and makes the new length about 5k.** I do the outlier removal like this

```
  for column in inputs:
    z_scores=abs(stats.zscore(df[column]))
    indexNames=df[(z_scores>3.0)].index.tolist()
      for index in indexNames:
          file.write('\n {0:s} outlier found with z-score {1:.2f}'.format(column, z_scores[index]))
    df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

I know there is an easier and more efficient way to do the snippet above but my goal is to write all the outlier values to a text file. This is why the snippet below is why I am posting on here. **The length of the z_scores array is about 5k as well**

```
file.write('\n {0:s} outlier found with z-score {1:.2f}'.format(column, z_scores[index]))
```

It looks like the **indexNames** variable is finding the index of the values that satisfy the z-score condition from the **old dataframe**, without the zeros removed. I know this because when I print indexNames, I get indexes above 5k and in the 10-50k range. How can indexNames contain indices above 5k when the new length of the df after the zero removal is only 5k?

If I fix indexNames to where it finds the indices of the values that satisfy the z-score condition for the new Dataframe not the old Dataframe as it is now doing, then the file.write statement should run properly.

Let me know if there's anything else I can give yall. I can also paste all my code somewhere but  can't post the csv file.

Comment: Hi Austin, great first post. You may want to include a sample of your original data, or even better a dataframe function that builds your datafram so we can better assist you. i.e. df=pd.DataFrame({'inputs': [....

Comment: @Gorlomi thanks for letting me know. I updated the post to add some of the stuff you wanted